# DRM Intel DP failure

Tags: intel-graphics, thinkpad, drm

I have a Thinkpad X1C (gen 3) with Arch Linux installed.
When I connect a monitor to the laptop DP it flicks on and off, some of the time causing kernel panic. 
Looking at the system log I see the following errors regarding the DP:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b 1 | grep drm | cut -d' ' -f 6- | sort | uniq
[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to get link status
[drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to get link status
[drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
```

#### System details

kernel: `Linux 4.8.6-2-ck`
xf86-video-intel: `1:2.99.917+725+gbf7316a-1`

Comment: I too have this, with X1Cg5 + Lenovo TB3 dock. Did your find a solution?

Comment: It was so long ago, I don't remember. I think I might have just moved to use the HDMI port.